# Background service in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I've got an application w. AppHost (inside `Startup.cs`) and also a `Configure.Db.cs` file.
I want to run a background service (Timer based) to routinely do some things, in addition to serving services.

If I add the timer inside Apphost's `Configure()`, which is run *before* the `Configure.Db`, I get into a problem as the background service is dependent on the Db to be configured.

Edit: I just found that it is possible to specify order of Modular startup: https://docs.servicestack.net/modular-startup#modular-startup-prioritization which means I can force the `Configure.db` to run before Apphost.

Anyway, am I going about this wrong? Should I perhaps have a separate AppHost just for the background job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend configuring a [Background MQ Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/background-mq) for executing Services in the background.

Comment: Can a Background MQ Service run at timed intervals? Assume I want it to do something every 10 minutes...

Comment: No, have a look at [Timed background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) in ASP.NET Core. Personally I'd prefer to have an OS scheduled task called a route periodically or if it's accessible over the internet use a service like uptimerobot or pingdom.

Comment: Timed background tasks looks like just a Timer executing tasks, so that's pretty much what I'm doing already, which is good to know. Only difference is that I stop the timer and start it after my task is done, so I get a "10 minute break" between runs, instead of running every 10 minutes.

Comment: How can Timed background tasks (IHostedService) be used together with Servicestack? Normally, a service inherits from ServiceStacks `Service`, but here @mythz refers to IHostedService. How is that accessible in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how to do this with hangfire by adding the mix

```
x mix hangfire-postgres
```

This will allow you to add services that fire in the background on a cron schedule.

To make it work without a database you need to change the postgres provider to the in-memory provider:  https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage